# Directly query TFS Warehouse using T-sql

Tags: sql-server, tfs

Hi I'm wondering if anybody has had any experience querying a Team Foundation Server store to retrieve current work item information. It is my understanding that the information I require is stored in the TFSWarehouse Database.

I'm well aware that there are APIs that provide this functionality and I've used them myself. However these come with the requirement to install Team Explorer on any client PC that will reference the API.

All I want is a list of Work Items with some selected fields such as Title, State and Created By.

Has anybody attempted this themselves, and indeed does anybody know of any pitfalls with this approach?

---------- EDIT 16/02

Just to add after speaking with TreeUK. What would be great is if anybody perhaps has an example query, or maybe some explanation as to the table structure?

Comment: Are you saying that in order to consume a TFS web service you have to have a TeamExplorer client installed in the client? Is it due to the licensing?

Comment: Hi, I'm not 100% sure whether or not using the API provided for TFS goes via web services, that's kind of irrelevant. If you install an app that references these API on a machine that does not have Team Explorer installed, the application fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the SQL database that hosts TFS, you can write a query that pulls this information out.

The database you want to look at is TFSWarehouse.
Below is a query that gets Work Item general information.

```
select System_Id as WorkItemId, System_Title as Title,
System_State as Status, System_Reason as Reason, 
System_WorkItemType as Type
from [Work Item]
```

It's kind of clear what they all do, check that table to get any other properties of interest.

Comment: That would be great, that's what I'm after really, a guide of what tables I should be getting the information from.

Comment: Great stuff thanks. Interesting to note that Microsoft uses a space in it's table names, I hate that!

Comment: If this is what you wanted, you should select this response as the answer. (Tick it on the left.)

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Work Item'.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2005, it'll need to be [workitemtracking].dbo.[workitemsare]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Top(100) FactWorkItemLinkHistory.WorkItemLinkTypeSK, DimWorkItemLinkType.LinkName, DimWorkItem.System_Id, DimWorkItem.System_Title
FROM FactWorkItemLinkHistory
     INNER JOIN DimWorkItemLinkType ON DimWorkItemLinkType.LinkID = FactWorkItemLinkHistory.WorkItemLinkTypeSK
     INNER JOIN DimWorkItem ON DimWorkItem.System_Id = FactWorkItemLinkHistory.SourceWorkItemID
WHERE FactWorkItemLinkHistory.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2013, it'll need to be [Your Tfs_Warehouse database].dbo.DimWorkItem

```sql
SELECT System_Id as WorkItemId, System_Title as Title,
System_State as Status, System_Reason as Reason, 
System_WorkItemType as Type
FROM dbo.DimWorkItem
```